# c++ expects ';' at end of member declaration when there is one

Tags: c++, g++

I have two errors that arise on the same line of code.
The following are snippets, only relevant code is there.

First is Database Class

```
#include "program.h"
using namespace std;
class Database {
public:
  Database(Program *program);
  ~Database();
};
```

Next is the Query Class.

```
#include "database.h"
using namespace std;

class Query {
public:
  Relation* evaluate(Database* database);
};
```

The line in question is:

```
Relation* evaluate(Database* database);
```

1. The first error is `"Database does not name a type"`, despite including the database.h file.
2. The second error is `"expected ';' after member declaration"` which I believe is related to the first.

Everything in this project has worked until the addition of this database class.

I am stumped on this one, and have been researching all over stackoverflow to no avail.
I am on Debian Stretch and compiling with g++. Does anyone have any ideas?

**EDIT**

Minimal compilable code:

query.h

```
#include "database.h"

class Query {
public:
  void evaluate(Database* database);
};
```

program.h

```
#include "query.h"
#include "database.h"

using namespace std;
class Program {
public:

};
```

database.h

```
#include "program.h"

class Database {
public:
  Database(Program *program);
};
```

Comment: What is the content of `program.h` ?

Comment: Don't post snippets, post something we can at least attempt to compile.

Comment: the first snippet is the stripped down code of database.h, and `#include "program.h"` is really only added for completeness, I don't believe it is relevant to this issue.

Comment: Get rid of the `using namespace std;` in the header files.

Comment: The issue is that it is a large project with hundreds of files, making that difficult to do.

Comment: You might try making a separate program with all the classes in the same file; then you could more easily track down the problem, on whether it's a syntactic or symantec error.

Comment: "I don't believe it is relevant to this issue." Don't delieve. Provide a [mcve] or it didn't happen.

Comment: I tried eliminating `using namespace` and it compiles with the same error. I will try Little Boy Blue's suggestion next.

Comment: I'll try and distill a compilable example.

Comment: @DallinHagman Not to spill out a namespace into the global namespace in headers (and in general) was just an advice unrelated to your problem.

Comment: This could be missing `}`  or `;` somewhere. Post `program.h` so we can reproduce.  With small addition of `class Relation` and `class Program` your code [compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/xhJhwD).

Comment: Maybe you have interdependent cycle of includes. `program.h` can include both `database.h` and `Query.h` and the include guard is already declared when entering `database.h`. If you use only pointers in Query and Database, just forward declare and remove includes.

Comment: ooo, I didn't catch that. I do in program.h how would I resolve that?

Comment: I also have `#define #ifndef` wrapped around all my classes

Comment: Voted to close for being a guessing game.

Comment: Again: Show. Real. Code.

Comment: If you would check my post, I added a complete, compilable, minimal, verifiable example. Allow me to make necessary edits to my question before you get impatient.

Comment: I saw your edit. And as you say: "Minimal compilable code" - it compiles. It doesn't reproduce your problem. Make a copy of your whole project, throw out all things that are not needed to reproduce the compiler errors you get now and then show **exactly** that code.

Comment: It sure does on my computer. I have an entirely separate folder with ONLY those header files, and I am able to produce the two errors. I am on debian compiling in g++ with command `g++ -g -Wall -Werror -std=c++17 *.h`

Comment: @KamilCuk Thank you for your suggestion. Forward declarations work on the minimal example, and I will be trying it on the full project now.

Comment: `g++ *.h` Are you compiling header files?

Comment: Your "minimal compilable code" consists of three `.h` files (no `.cpp` files). with circular dependencies. What exactly did you compile, and how? If your headers have include guards, you need to show them. (And normally you wouldn't compile `.h` files.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try out the `-E` option of the compiler: it causes the source code to be preprocessed, i.e., you'll see the code as it is seen by the compiler. If you look at your headers closely you'll see that there are cyclic dependencies between the different types. You'll need to break them.

The "easy" fix is to declare the `Database` class in `query.h`:

```
class Database;

class Query {
public:
    void evaluate(Database* database);
};
```

While this will fix the shown problem, cyclic dependencies will come and haunt you. In general they are bad. A system of class which cyclicly depend on each other are effectively just one component and should probably be all declared in just one header.